# Java illegal argument exception when setting Json value using groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to set  'code'  value as 'Test2' for given Json using groovy but i get Java illegal argument exception  while setting the value.

Raw request:

```
{
    "langauageCode": "en-US",
    "Test": [{
        "_modificationTypeCode": "added",
        "allocationTypeCode": "3",
        "code": "Test1"
    }]
}
```

Here is the code I am using

```
def jsonRequest = slurper.parseText(rawRequest)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(jsonRequest)
builder.content.Test.code ='Test2' //Throwing java illegal argument but when I print using log.info I get the value
 log.info("testbuilder " + builder.content.Test.code)
```

Can some one please let me know while I am setting the value why I am getting Java illegal argument exception?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Test` is an array. if you want to set the `code`, you need to:

```
builder.content.Test[0].code = 'Test2'
```